# how to convert 48bit RRRRGGGGBBBB color into 24bit RRGGBB color format

Tags: c, colors

I have a sensor Which  gives the vibgyor's each colour in 16bit format, now I want to generate a 24bit color using that vibgyor's data. Please guide me someone how to do this conversion. Thank you in advance.
-Dhananjay

Comment: I want to generate the color of 24bit RGB type.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: I will use C language.

Answer (score 1):

Both color dephs use hexademical numbers, so u don't need any special formula for convertion.

You can just copy most significant 8-bits(2 first symbols of each channel) into the respective planes.

For example,

```
#2343ff45ee12 = #23ffee
```

This is only an approximate value, and you can not get more accurate. But most monitors only display 24 bits anyway.

Reverse convertion looks like:

```
 #23ffee = #2300ff00ee00
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @raven cler, Can I get sRGB colours by following this method? or Do I need to follow any other method to convert to the sRGB format.